# Only display first instance of an unknown class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is this possible with CSS?
I want to only display the first instance of an unknown class, or do I need to use Javascript?

```
<div class="agendaDay apr24">24 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr24">24 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr25">25 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr26">26 April</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div class="agendaDay apr24">24 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr24" style="display:none">24 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr25">25 April</div>
<div class="agendaDay apr26">26 April</div>
```

Basically.  I won't know what the class name is, but wondering if there's someway I can select potentially repeating class names using css.

Comment: Considering you can't do this at all when you *know* the class, I would say no.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but that question is not it.

Comment: If you know the class name I guess it's barely possible but if you don't then, obviously, no.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
.apr24:nth-child(2){
   display: none;
}
```

With css3 you can do this:

```
div[class*="apr24"]:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}
```

that mean is if a div has the class apr24 do something.

Answer (score 0):

**If you know the class name** (which is **not** the specific case), you can use a trick with `:first-of-type` selector,

```
.apr24 {display: none}
.apr24:first-of-type {display: block}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9auxL50u/2/)

However, if you're allowed to use javascript **eventually**, you can use `:contains` to target a specific text and display the first one. Like this :

```
$('div:contains("24 April")').hide().first().show();
```

[Fiddle with js possibility](https://jsfiddle.net/9auxL50u/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, as not being able to do this via CSS, here is my solution in JS.

```
$(".agendaDay").each(function(i, obj) {
    if(i>0){
        if($(".agendaDay:eq("+i+")").attr("rel") == $(".agendaDay:eq("+(i-1)+")").attr("rel")){
                    $(".agendaDay:eq("+i+")").attr("hidden","hidden");
        }
    }
}
```

After rendering the page, I am looking through each div, if the "rel" attribute of the previous div equals the current one then I am hiding the current div.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you know the class names, do something similar:

```
.apr24 {
    display: block;
}

.apr24 ~ .apr24 {
    display: none;
}
```

The `~` CSS selector picks all siblings, which you can hide.

---

I assume that you're doing some logic on the backend when generating your list of agenda HTML, so if you're using SCSS/LESS then you could do:

```
# HTML
<section class="agendaMonth">
    <div class="agendaDay d24">24 April</div>
    <div class="agendaDay d24">24 April</div>
    <div class="agendaDay d25">25 April</div>
    <div class="agendaDay d26">26 April</div>
</section>
```

And the CSS can be generated like this:

```
# SCSS
@for $i from 1 through 31 {
    SECTION.agendaMonth DIV.d#{$i} ~ DIV.d#{$i} {display: none;}
}
```

The reason you need the SECTION-tag is to "interrupt" the sibling-selector, so it doesn't target `d24` in any later months.

Hope this helps.